# Jenkins Job watch - machine specific

Tags: jenkins, command-prompt, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins with multiple jobs assigned to multiple machines.
I am trying to do a machine cleanup (Deleting temporary files and views from clearcase which are old enough). For that i need to check if there is any ongoing job running on that machine. Is it possible through some commands or any plugin to jenkins?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All my slaves are single threaded. That means when my cleanup jobs run on that machine, no other job runs. You can employ that same technology as well. However, you might need to use [Heavy Job Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Heavy+Job+Plugin) and set the job weight to the number of executors of the slave(s).

Comment: Hey thanks Peter but can you define single threaded job through jenkins? I mean how can you configure this?

Comment: ok Got it..but i need multi thread nodes so for now will use the plugin but alternative solution is wlc